# How parse serialized form data to json using Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, socket.io

I use Angular and Node.js + Express 4 + socket.io.

I want send form to the server throw socket.io. I created a service in my Angular app which returns serialized form data. This service works the same way as jQuery.serialize().

Then I send serialized data to the server using socket.io. How can I parse this data to the JSON object? I have express body-parse but I don't know how to use it not like a express middleware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize), the `jQuery.serialize()` will create a query string with the form elements in the following form (example):

```
single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1
```

To parse a query string into an object, you can use the [querystring](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) Node.js module:

```
var qs = require('querystring')
qs.parse('single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1')
// Prints:
{ single: 'Single',
  multiple: [ 'Multiple', 'Multiple3' ],
  check: 'check2',
  radio: 'radio1' }
```